# Error at "dbms_output.put_line"?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am creating a trigger in Oracle and we are stuggling with the syntax.

I have run it through a code checker several times but it keep saying we have an error at "dbms_output.put_line".

When we try to run it, the code says "trigger created with compilation errors"

```
CREATE TRIGGER date_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON PrintJob
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF StartDate > SysDate THEN 
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line ('Please check date');
  END;
```

Comment: It looks like your trigger has some syntax errors. If you publish it we'll can appoint to them.

Comment: This trigger looks incomplete, I guess :) Generally, it contains at least four errors: 1) END IF not found when expected, 2) END (of trigger) not found when expected, 3) StartDate is undefined, maybe you mean :new.StartDate, 4) dbms_output is senseless here, maybe you mean raise_application_error.

Comment: If you create it in IDE, IDE should show errors. If you create in SQLPlus, just execute `show errors` to see errors.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse.

I have now tried:

set serveroutput on
CREATE TRIGGER date_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON PrintJob
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF New.StartDate > SysDate
THEN 
raise_application_error
END IF
END;

I have now spent 8 hours on this one and I am about ready to cry.

Comment: Thanks all, its not working with 


Set Server Output on
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER date_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON PrintJob
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :new.StartDate > SYSDATE
THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'Please check date');
END IF;
END;
/

Comment: `set serveroutput on` should not be part of the PL/SQL code. Some IDEs allow you to place multiple commands on one page and run them as a script, but ideally you would use a proper PL/SQL code editor that highlights compiler errors.

Comment: BTW, for RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR, you don't need to SET SERVEROUTPUT ON (but you do for DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE).

Comment: I just wanted to thank everyone for their help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Trigger can't reference table columns just by naming them - you'll need :old (or :new) pseudorecord qualifiers, such as in this *modified* example. It is not that DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE won't work; you wrote it correctly, but should replace it with the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE printjob (startdate DATE);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER date_trigger
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON PrintJob
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     IF :new.StartDate > SYSDATE
  7     THEN
  8        -- dbms_output.put_line ('Please check date');
  9        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000, 'Please check date');
 10     END IF;
 11  END;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL> INSERT INTO printjob
  2       VALUES (DATE '2018-02-20');
INSERT INTO printjob
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Please check date
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.DATE_TRIGGER", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.DATE_TRIGGER'


SQL>
```